# How to publish an app on Android play store only for those users who already have the app installed?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I want to publish a private app on play store. My use case is that we are going to distribute some Android devices with a specific pre-installed application. This app should not be visible to any other Android user (who does not have the app already installed on the device). We are going to install the app initially on Android devices by ourself using the APK file directly. Then onwards, those users should be able to get the update from play store for the app whenever we want to upload the updated version. But other Android users should not be able to see the app. Only those users who have the app installed should be able to see it. I can't use enterprise email id solution for the private app as those users will use their personal Gmail account on the device. Beta testing solution can also not be used due to its limit.

Comment: The play store does not support what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is that easy, especially if you only install the the APK, the user can uninstall the app and then never get it again, for something like that you have to contact google directly.

**EDIT:** since, you install an apk, you don't have to follow google-play policy, and program an updater inside the app, that will update itself

Comment: If the user uninstalls the app then he can contact us for the APK.

Comment: since, you install an apk, you dont have to follow googles apk rules, and programm an updater inside the app, that will update itself

Comment: We have tried that solution as well. The only issue is that "Install app from unknown sources" setting should be enabled to support it. We are just looking for a better solution using google play store update infra.

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK** there are no such options provided by Google Play Store.The only possible way for this is using **Internal**,**Alpha** or **Beta** testing only.
For more info refer link [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en).Other than this it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Note - I don't recommend doing this, and it is so hacky I wouldn't build a business on doing this. But ...

*Option 1*

Apps that are "unpublished" on the Play store are invisible to any user who has not installed the app before. But updates can still be given to users who already have the app.  See [the documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476)

So you could publish your app very briefly, install on the devices, then unpublish it. After this you could send updates using Play.

The caveats are that "existing users" is exactly that - users. Not devices. So any user account that had the app installed could install it on another device, not just the device that already has it.

*Option 2*

If all you were worried about was other users installing it, not other users seeing it, and you have control over the system image of your device then you have another option. You could add into your manifest a [uses-feature](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) element like:

```
<uses-feature
  android:name="a.very.unique.feature.name.that.only.my.devices.have"
  android:required="true"/>
```

Then make sure that feature is in the available features for the System rom for your device. This is obviously only available if you are a manufacturer and setting the system image for your device. It is also not secure - anyone with a custom rom can fake the features. But it might be good enough for you.

You could also do a combination of both, which is what phone manufacturers often do for apps only available on certain phones.